# Down for maintenance. See our blog?

Tags: discussion, downtime

While SO is down (and other sites) they link to the [ServerFault](http://blog.serverfault.com) blog. That's fine with me. However what if all sites go down (what just happened). The link to ServerFault´s blog also doesn't work anymore then. Perhaps it would be nice to link to something else then?

Or just remove the link to the blog all together.

Comment: Actually, SF's blog was up during the outage.

Comment: @Kevin No it wasn't I got an error page. Or was it a glitch that just happened to be be at the same time as the maintenance outage?

Comment: I clicked on the link from the "We're down" page and got it just fine.

Comment: I didn't get the page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had to pull down the blogs, the latest post had a couple of very large images in it (this will be fixed!) as well as our offline pages not pulling from the CDN yet. The traffic was saturating our internet uplink which caused our remote people to not be able to work over the VPN as well as timeouts etc for some people on the offline pages - if you've ever tried remote connections over a slow or saturated link you'll know what that is like. You can get things done, but well it is SLLLOOWWWWWW.

[image: Network Utilization during outage]

Comment: So, the important takeaways are: a) Stack Exchange employees can work from home, and b) they are forced to work on weekends.  Awesome =)

Comment: Takeaway - @casperOne never worked for an employer where every minute of downtime was costing $$$ ;)

Comment: @casperOne Re a), I'm quite glad I don't have to make the commute from Berlin to New York every morning. The trans-atlantic bridges are always a bottleneck.

Answer (score 3):

Funny story - we were planing on having the blog up, however there were a few images that were quite larger than they should have been.  This ended up saturating our upstream bandwidth and we pulled it.

[image: offline death]

Comment: Tsk tsk. Images that are not web optimized? On the SO blog?

Comment: @Oded SF blog, not SO blog

Comment: @JeffAtwood - Much worse then...

Comment: I'm more surprised that VPN traffic shares the same uplink as web-traffic for this very reason.

Comment: Sorry about that, guys -- apparently the status screenshot I took was a whopping 600k, which was pretty big.  I take responsibility for this one; I only hope it results in a gold badge of shame.

Comment: @mdmarra its due to the way the colo charges for bandwith, one large file transfer could easily double our bill

Comment: @Zypher interesting. I'll have to bug you or Pete about this in chat on Monday.